# Linux KProbe in Raspberry PI

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, raspberry-pi4, kprobe

I am trying to use kprobes on Raspberry pi and and trying to store get the file struct from in the post handler of k_probe using the register struct pt_regs. I can't seem to figure out what register to fetch it from. In x86 it's ax so using below works.

```
struct file *file = (struct file *)regs->ax;
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What Raspberry PI version are you using? Could you share the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: output of uname -a: `Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux`
its a raspberry pi 4

Comment: Could you try `regs->uregs[0]` and, if that doesn't work, `ctx->regs[0]`? I'd expect it to be the first since you're on arm (vs. aarch64).

Comment: I used the first and I get this error: `/tmp/ccQD2dnt.s: Assembler messages:`
`/tmp/ccQD2dnt.s:43: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- mrs r4,cntvct_el0'`
`/tmp/ccQD2dnt.s:394: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- mrs r0,cntvct_el0'`

Comment: Did you try the second?

Comment: @pchaigno yes I did. It says no member named ctx.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant `regs->regs[0]` since you named your context argument `regs`.

Comment: This is the error when I used regs->regs[0] : `‘struct pt_regs’ has no member named ‘regs’; did you mean ‘uregs’?` It gives me an assembler error when I use regs->uregs[0] as mentioned above.

Comment: @pchaigno Any Leads?